# Why does this code allow one less player to be entered than numPlayers?

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and coding in general. This code is meant to input an integer from the user for number of players, and then input the names of players totaling that player number; however, when run it allows for one less name to be entered.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
//import java.util.Scanner;

    public class FarkleFactory {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Welcome and set-up for a Farkle game

            int numPlayers;
            String playerOrder;

            System.out.println ("Let's play Farkle!");
            //Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            TextIO input = new TextIO();

            System.out.println("How many players will there be?");
            numPlayers = input.getInt();
            String[] players = new String[numPlayers];
            System.out.println("Roll the dice and determine who starts...");
            System.out.println("Enter the players.");

            for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)  { 
                players[i] = TextIO.getln();
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(players));
            System.out.println ("OK, " + players[1] + "! Roll the dice and get started!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `TextIO.getln();`? What is the behaviour of your program? What is wrong with it?

Comment: I don't use TextIO, but where are you creating a TextIO variable, input, assigning it a TextIO object, and then not use it when getting input in the for loop?

Comment: Hmmm.. it works if I use `BufferedReader br = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` and  then `players[i] = br.readLine();`

Comment: I am using TextIO as an alternative to Scanner for user input. The program asks how many players and then puts that integer in the array elements, for instance - [4] . When names of players are input the program stops inputting at 3 names and prints out with a comma just after the bracket -     [, first name, second name, third name]

Comment: This was also happening with Scanner. Although I'll have to study a bit, I'll try the McPeak example...

Comment: No need to try my `BufferedReader` example.  I think I see your problem (answer below)

Comment: Hovercraft - I added TextIO.java to the source as directed by someone. Not sure I follow what you're asking but I'm new. The program works other than the number of names allowed to be inputted is off by one.

Comment: Sorry @Matthew, I don't see anything "below"...

Comment: That's excellent, Matthew! Worked like a charm... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
numPlayers = input.getInt();
```

with

```
numPlayers = input.getlnInt();
```

Otherwise, the newline from your entry for "number of players" is being read as the name of the 1st player.